# Is it possible to introspect on methods using Boost Hana?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++14, generic-programming, boost-hana

[**Boost Hana**](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) provides the ability to introspect on class member fields in a simple and beautiful way:

```
// define:

struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
};

// below could be done inline, but I prefer not polluting the 
// declaration of the struct
BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(not_my_namespace::Person, name, age);

// then:

Person john{"John", 30};
hana::for_each(john, [](auto pair) {
  std::cout << hana::to<char const*>(hana::first(pair)) << ": "
            << hana::second(pair) << std::endl;
});
```

However, the documentation only mentions member *fields*. I would like to introspect on methods also. I've tried to naively extend the example with a method:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string get_name() const { return "louis"; }
};

BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(::Foo, get_name);
```

This compiles. However, as soon as I try to use it, using code similar to the above (`for_each`...), I get many compile errors. Since there are no examples that show introspection of methods, I'm wondering whether it is supported.

Comment: It is supported, but I agree that it could be documented better. You can look at the _Minimal complete definition_ section of the [`Struct`](http://ldionne.com/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1Struct.html) concept. I don't have time to compose a full answer right now, but I'll try to do it in the next days (and also update the tutorial).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My original answer was crap; sorry for that. Here's a rewrite that actually answers the question.

I just added a macro to allow easily defining a `Struct` with custom accessors. Here's how you could do it:

```
#include <boost/hana/adapt_adt.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/string.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct Person {
    Person(std::string const& name, int age) : name_(name), age_(age) { }
    std::string const& get_name() const { return name_; }
    int get_age() const { return age_; }
private:
    std::string name_;
    int age_;
};

BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_ADT(Person,
    (name, [](auto const& p) { return p.get_name(); }),
    (age, [](auto const& p) { return p.get_age(); })
);

int main() {
    Person bob{"Bob", 30};
    assert(hana::at_key(bob, BOOST_HANA_STRING("name")) == "Bob");
    assert(hana::at_key(bob, BOOST_HANA_STRING("age")) == 30);
}
```

That code should work on `master`. Otherwise, if you need more control over the definition of your accessors or the keys used to map to them, you can also define the whole thing by hand:

```
namespace boost { namespace hana {
    template <>
    struct accessors_impl<Person> {
        static auto apply() {
            return hana::make_tuple(
                hana::make_pair(BOOST_HANA_STRING("name"), [](auto&& p) -> std::string const& {
                    return p.get_name();
                }),
                hana::make_pair(BOOST_HANA_STRING("age"), [](auto&& p) {
                    return p.get_age();
                })
            );
        }
    };
}}
```

You can find more information about how to define `Struct`s in the [reference](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html) for the `Struct` concept.

Comment: @seertaak Does that answer your question? If so, could you please accept it and otherwise, please let me know what's missing so I can help you and perhaps improve the usability of the library.

Comment: Yes, it does! Apologies for the late reply.